Salesforce CPQ - Asynchronous processing of QCP and price rules resulting in incorrect ACV calculations
We have a scenario where changing the Billing Country outside QLE triggers the Price Rule to set the Partner Discount at QL, which is then used to set the Net Total at QL. In parallel, the QCP script also executes upon a Billing Country change to calculate the ACV = Net Total / 12.
Since both processes run in parallel, the QCP may execute before the Price Rule has updated the Net Total with the applied Partner Discount, resulting in an incorrect ACV calculation.
However, running the QCP manually twice corrects the issue, as the QCP gets the updated Net Total value on the second run.
Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?
